# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, razor

I have an ASP.Net MVC Entity Framework project which is working fine on local machine. But when I upload it to Azure Web App, I get following error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor,
>   Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or
>   one of its dependencies.

Full screenshot
[image]

The version I have referenced in project is 3.0.0.0 and same is present in `bin` folder. I have cleaned and rebuild project several times and also deleted `obj` and `bin` directories but in vain.

Why is it trying to find version 2.0.0.0 when I have referenced 3.0.0.0?

Comment: I updated MVC via Nuget on local machine. Then rebuilt and uploaded to Azure but same issue. Also added following line in web.config but same issue. `<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages.Razor" PublicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>`

Comment: what is yours.net framework version ?

Comment: My version is 4.5. And on Azure it's 4.7. I seem to have solved this issue but now I am facing another one and that is too many redirects. Now when I open website it says too many redirects.